# How to serialize a Django model using Graphene-Django outside the context of a graphQL query

Tags: graphql, django-orm, graphene-python, graphene-django

I'm using Graphene-Django to build a GraphQL API, and I've [defined object types as explained in the docs](https://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/queries/). By way of example,

```py
import graphene
from graphene_django import DjangoObjectType

from .models import Question

class QuestionType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ("id", "question_text")

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    questions = graphene.List(QuestionType)
    question_by_id = graphene.Field(QuestionType, id=graphene.String())

    def resolve_questions(root, info, **kwargs):
        # Querying a list
        return Question.objects.all()

    def resolve_question_by_id(root, info, id):
        # Querying a single question
        return Question.objects.get(pk=id)
```

This works fine for fetching the content of a `Question` model in a GraphQL query, but I'd also like to serialize my `Question` objects to a JSON representation in log files and tests. I can write a separate utility function, but it seems redundant when I already have an existing GraphQL schema that defines which objects fields I'm interested in and how to serialize them.

Basically, I'm looking for a Graphene analogue to [using a DRF serializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#serializing-objects)

```py
serializer = CommentSerializer(comment)
serializer.data
# {'email': 'leila@example.com', 'content': 'foo bar', 'created': '2016-01-27T15:17:10.375877'}
```

Ideally, I'm looking for something like

```py
from my_app.schema import QuestionType
from my_app.models import Question

question_object = Quest.objects.get(pk=1)
data = QuestionType.to_dict(question_object)
```

I've looked at the Graphene docs, and poked around [the source on Github](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene) but it all seems very obfuscated and I can't find an obvious way to do what I want.

Can anyone offer a concise example of using a Graphene ObjectType to serialize a single model instance outside the entire GraphQL query context?